# Javascript MVC Two way binding Without Framwork dependency

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I need a solution with a minimal library which helps me to track M<->V changes (two way binding). We have a constraint of libary size not more than 7kb.   We are looking for good minimal code that helps to solve this problem. We have tried backbone and we would like to hear or know any other open source code that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try RivetJs its just 6.2kb when minified
supports two way binding

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikeric/rivets/v0.9.4/dist/rivets.bundled.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried Angular1 and size of library more than 45kb (1.2 legacy)  and we tried to embed ng-model attribute with the third party components. To detect the changes we need to fire $scope.apply and we have ruled because of performance issue.

Comment: Check if any of these helps

Comment: Hi @rakeshjojosri, did your question get resolved ? are you able to conclude which one to use?